# Verifying Solidity signature returns invalid signature with recover

Tags: solidity, web3js, signature

I am working on a project for which I need to generate a hash on the serverside and verify it using a contract. I'm in the early stage and trying to get it to work with a very simple contract that just verifies the signed hash.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";

contract SigTest {

    using ECDSA for bytes32;

    address private systemAddress;

    constructor (address _systemAddress) {
        systemAddress = _systemAddress;
    }

    function isValidSignature(bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature) internal view returns (bool isValid) {
        bytes32 signedHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash));
        return signedHash.recover(signature) == systemAddress;
    }

    function isDataValid(string memory mess, bytes memory signature) public view returns (bool){
        // Build the hash and check the sig
        // We only accept sigs from the system
        bytes32 msgHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, mess));
        require(
            isValidSignature(msgHash, signature),          
            "Invalid signature"
        );
        return true;
    }
}
```

When, in Remix, I sign message "helloworld" with the same account I used as `systemAddress` and I pass both the resulting hash and "helloworld" as params to `isDataValid` it will fail the `require` and return `Invalid Signature`.

The same message is displayed when I try the same with NodeJS where I use a timestamp (and uint256) instead of a string

Server Side:

```
export default function Hash(req, res) {
    let web3 = new Web3("wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/<INFURA_ID>")
    let wallet = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY)

    let timestamp = Date.now()
    let hash = wallet.sign(timestamp)
    res.status(200).json({timestamp: timestamp, hash: hash })
}
```

FrontEnd:

```
function getHash(){
        axios.post("/api/hash").then((res) => {
            setHash(JSON.stringify(res.data.hash))

            let tx = contract.methods.isDataValid(res.data.timestamp, web3.utils.asciiToHex(res.data.hash.messageHash.substring(2))).call()

            tx.then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: You aren't using hash.signature, that should be the signature. It seems you are signing a message timestamp, but the solidity function verifies something else.

Comment: Even when ignoring the JS code and manually signing a message using Remix, it still returns `invalid signature`. Even though I use the `systemAddress` to sign it.

Comment: You aren't using the sign and recover primitives correctly so there's no way they will work.